# Automatically deploying Service Fabric application with Jenkins produces "target does not exist" error

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, azure-service-fabric

When attempting to automatically build a Service Fabric application using Jenkins, the application builds and fine using the MSBuild plugin but at the moment it reaches the package target it halts, citing that a class library dependency of shared code does not have a "Package" target.

The project is built in earlier steps, however fails at this point:

```
/p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64 /target:App-Core\App-Core:Package
```

Note that the sln file that contains this application is also specified and definitely exists at the provided location (debug is intentional as we are using this machine as a "proving ground" before it hits production). Additionally, "App-Core\App-Core" is a folder structure that points at the .sfproj file.

When it attempts this step we finally hit the error:

```
D:\Jenkins\workspace\App-Core\App\Common\Common\Common.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "Package" does not exist in the project
```

This "Common" project does exist at this location and contains non-service fabric specific code that we share between services and we would expect that it would copy the DLL to the required locations instead of packaging the project. What are we missing here?

Comment: Welcome to S.O Ned. Are you tested the deploy to Service Fabric **without** Jenkins? It works without jenkins?

Comment: Thank you! It works as expected in Visual Studio when pushing the publish button; I have heard that msbuild outside of VS is a lot more strict in what it what it will accept. When manually run with solely msbuild and not Jenkins the build will also fail, which confuses me as I am led to believe that VS also uses msbuild anyway.

Comment: Nice!! If this was useful and/or was the solution to your problem, please give a like to my comment :D

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I was thanking you for the welcome haha! Unfortunately not the solution, the project still doesn't build automatically inside Jenkins; we originally had Jenkins invoke VS from the command line to package the application and that worked for while, however we came to the conclusion that the CI shoukd run msbuild instead as installing a full copy of VS with all the workloads we need on every slave agent is inefficient and time consuming.

Comment: Your commands or scripts must work correctly before trying to run them with jenkins. Is this your case?

Comment: The script executes fully occasionally (going all the way to successfully deploying in the cluster), something changes in the project files that makes msbuild choke at the packaging stage, even if it makes it all the way through a full recompile prior to packaging. So the script will work but something Visual Studio is doing is incompatible with the standalone msbuild.

Comment: As you said : **is incompatible with the standalone msbuild**, so you need to fix this before trying to do with jenkins

Comment: But Jenkins is just using the standalone msbuild, so there is/should be no difference if I execute msbuild under Jenkins or not, the problem surely would still lie in the way that msbuild is being configured by the solution files?

Comment: My point is : Your command must work fine before trying to execute it with jenkins. If your command works in simple cmd but does not work in jenkins, this will indicate some error in jenkins.

Comment: My bad, sorry. I went down that path already quite a while ago, it gets the same result regardless of Jenkins invoking msbuild or not; in the command line it still errors out in the exact same way.